# Android NavigationDrawer image

Tags: android

I implemented the Navigation Drawer, but now I want to insert an image for each line of text.
I did not find information in the official guide. thanks

```
mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        mGalaxyTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.drawer_list_item, mGalaxyTitles));
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            selectItem(0);}
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,         
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,  
                R.string.hello_world,  
                R.string.hello_world  
                ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); 
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); 
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create your own adapter, as you would do for any kind of list.

for instance, you make your  `R.layout.drawer_list_ite`m look like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="6dip" android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:singleLine="true"  " />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then, you create your own adapter

```
public class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
  private final Context context;
  private final String[] values;
  private final int layout;
 private final int []images;

  public MyArrayAdapter(Context context, int layout, String[] values, int [] images) {
    super(context,  layout, values);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
    this.layout=layout;
    this.images=images;
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.text);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    textView.setText(values[position]);
      imageView.setImageResource(images[position]);


    return rowView;
  }
}
```

And then, in your activity you create an array of image resources, something like:

```
int[] mImages = new int[]{R.drawable.IMAGE1,R.drawable.IMAGE2,R.drawable.IMAGE3, ...};
```

and finally you change this line in your code

```
mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.drawer_list_item, mGalaxyTitles));
```

to this, where you assign your addapter to the list:

```
mDrawerList.setAdapter(new MyArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.drawer_list_item, mGalaxyTitles, mImages));
```

You can follow the [vogella's tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) if you want a good understanding.